# Alternatives to rendering in browser, using pio.renderers.default = ""

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

Got very happy when I learned the potential of applying plotly in my use of Python. I use PyCharm, and found out that I could depict numbers, figures, stats, etc using the above option. Yet I am bit confused. First, executing code including 'import plotly.io as pio' and on the following line 'pio.renderers.default = "browser"' it takes ages for the data and graphics to load, but almost only a split second to open the browser. Second, is there an alternative to the "browser"-choice, e.g. a choice that allowed fig.show() directly in the PyCharm console? - for jupyter I think the alternative is "notebook", but that is not PyCharm. If alternatives exist to pio, i.e. that prompt rendering of code execution in the console, I'd be all ears and eyes. Thx, in advance, for any advice.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff 
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

## Create first figure
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"
x1,y1 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2, .2), np.arange(0, 2, .2))
u1 = np.cos(x1)*y1
v1 = np.sin(x1)*y1

fig1 = ff.create_quiver(x1, y1, u1, v1, name='Quiver')

fig1.show()

## Create second figure
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(x, y)
u = -1 - X**2 + Y
v = 1 + X - Y**2

fig2 = ff.create_streamline(x, y, u, v, arrow_scale=.1, name='Steamline')

fig2.show()
```

Sometimes results are indeed rendered in a browser, mostly the browser stops loading and an utterly blank, white screen keeps staring at me. That is why I'd kind of fancied a rendering result as performed in matplotlib where graphics is shown in the console directly.

Comment: Have you tried setting the renderer to “png”?

Comment: Just did. Got this....ValueError: 
The orca executable is required to export figures as static images,
but it could not be found on the system path.

Comment: Then the "browser"-setting is a better alternative...;o/…;o)

Comment: Ok, have you tried installing Orca? It’s pretty easy :)

Comment: You know what, I think this is a memory-issue

Comment: Did install orca

Comment: 1.5.1 is the version

Comment: Does either png or browser mode work well with simpler charts?

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#builtin-renderers has bits on selecting the renderer. PyCharm might have a Jupyter-ish implementation, but probably not a full renderer of its own.

Answer (score 2):

The official answer to your question is that you can use other renderers like “png” or “svg” as provided by Orca. If your figure is too complex, however, you may have trouble with any renderer, depending on your hardware setup.

More info here: https://plot.ly/python/renderers/

Comment: Here is one more potential value... `pio.renderers.default = "iframe"`